# git_remote_fetch returns error with message : "there is no TLS stream available"

Tags: c++, fetch, libgit2

I am trying to fetch from my remote repository on BitBucket.  git_remote_fetch returns error with message:

```
there is no TLS stream available
```

Some ideas how to fix that?

Here is my code :

```
if(error = git_remote_fetch(remote, NULL,NULL,"fetch")!=0) {
    const git_error *lastError = giterr_last();
    cerr << "problem with fetch, error message : '" << lastError->message <<"'"<< endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when trying to use Python and pygit2 (which in turn depends on libgit2) to pull from a git repository. I am using a self-compiled version of libgit2 (0.25.0).

Recompiling libgit2 with the following flag solved the issue: `cmake -DCURL=OFF` as described in issue #3786[1] of the libgit2 project.

Full process of compiling as per pygit2 documentation[2] with added flag:

```
$ wget https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/archive/v0.25.0.tar.gz
$ tar xzf v0.25.0.tar.gz
$ cd libgit2-0.25.0/
$ cmake -DCURL=OFF .
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Make sure to delete the build directory of libgit2 if you compiled it once earlier because otherwise the flag will have no effect.

[1] https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/3786
[2] http://www.pygit2.org/install.html#quick-install

If you use the built-in version of libgit of your OS I suggest trying to use a compiled version.